# DOS -> path w. braces ->x64 prompt calll x86 exe?

Tags: dos, command-prompt

How can I call from a x64 command prompt an x86 exe file (containing a curly braces in its path) ? E.g.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\theExe.exe
```

If I do, the following:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\
```

and than call the exe, it works. However, if I call it, as wanted, I get an error, that the exe is mistyped or not existing..

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Actually, I was facing another problem, w/o realizin it:  starting from the command prompt an x86 exe on a x64 Windows XP OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround your dir in quotes

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\exe"
```

Also see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/302718/how-to-call-an-exe-from-a-different-folder-in-windows-command-line) on superuser.

Comment: I give you the point, although it turned out, that it was not my problem. The problem was, starting from the command prompt an x86 exe from a x64 Windows XP OS... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses (what you call curly braces) are not the problem. The spaces cause the cmd parser to interpret c:\Program as the command and the remainder as parameters.

The solution is to enclose the entire path in quotes. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\theExe.exe"`

Comment: Thank you. The spaces could be substituted by a '_' or %20, however, I coudlnt find a substitution for the '('. Anyway, the problem turned out to be a different one... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Double quotes: `"` `"`

```
cd "Program Files (x86)"
```